# Alfresco 5.1 document root object

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

my workflow.get.js file

```
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$TrainerEmpanelment";
workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "test";
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowPriority"] = "2";
workflow.parameters["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
workflow.parameters["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
var today = new Date();
var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
workflow.execute(document);
```

when using webscript i getting error

> The Web Script /alfresco/s/workflow/ has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.
>
> 500 Description:   An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Message:   06190087 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06190504 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': 06190503 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>
> Exception: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError - ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1728)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.gen._triggerworkflow_get_js__in_repository_store_workspace___SpacesStore_Company_Home_Data_Dictionary_Web_Scripts__414._c_script_0(/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts):11)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.gen._triggerworkflow_get_js__in_repository_store_workspace___SpacesStore_Company_Home_Data_Dictionary_Web_Scripts__414.call(/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts))
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>       org.mozilla.javascript.gen._triggerworkflow_get_js__in_repository_store_workspace___SpacesStore_Company_Home_Data_Dictionary_Web_Scripts__414.call(/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts))
>       org.mozilla.javascript.gen._triggerworkflow_get_js__in_repository_store_workspace___SpacesStore_Company_Home_Data_Dictionary_Web_Scripts__414.exec(/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts))
>   org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:502)
>       org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:200)
>       org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
>       org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
>       org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1376)
>       org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:512)
>       org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:580)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:649)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:421)
>       org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:301)
>       org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
>       org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
>       org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Exception: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException - 06190503 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>        org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:526)
>
> Exception: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 06190504 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': 06190503 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>           org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:204)
>
> Exception: org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 06190087 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06190504 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': 06190503 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>           org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1138)

Server: Community v5.1.0 (r122274-b3) schema 9,016
Time:   Jul 19, 2016 5:01:29 PM

Comment: Are you writing a Rule or a Webscript? Only your code looks to be in the right style for a Rule on a folder, not for a javascript webscript

Answer (score 0):

Can you Please try with this code

```
var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$TrainerEmpanelment");
var package= workflow.createPackage();
var workflow = new Array();

workflow["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
workflow["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "test";
workflow["bpm:workflowPriority"] = "2";
workflow["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
workflow["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 

var today = new Date();
var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 

workflow["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, workflow);
```